# copying an substring to string

Tags: c, string

i'm trying to get a 2 strings from the user and the second one will be the "needle" to copy to the first string
for example: 
string 1 (user input): eight height freight
string 2 (user input): eight
output: EIGHT hEIGHT frEIGHT

[for example i want to print: toDAY is a good DAY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2v07N.png)

having trouble copying multiple needles in stack
i have tried using while (*str) {rest of the function with str++}
i would love some explanation

```
  #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
    #define N 101
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <conio.h>

    void replaceSubstring(char* str, char* substr);
    void main() {
        int flag = 1;
        char str[N], substr[N];
        //char* str_ptr = &str, * substr_ptr = &substr; //creating pointer for the sake of while

        while (flag) {
            printf("\nEnter main text: ");
            gets_s(str,N);
            if (!str)
                flag = 0;
            printf("\nEnter sub-text: ");
            gets_s(substr,N);
            if (!str)
                flag = 0;
            replaceSubstring(str, substr);
            printf("%s",str);
            }
        printf("\nExited. (press any key to exit)");    
    }
    void replaceSubstring(char* str, char* substr) {
        int lensbstr;
        str = strstr(str, substr);
        _strupr(substr); //cnvrt to UPPERCASE
        lensbstr = strlen(substr); //length of the mutual string
        if (str)
            strncpy(str, substr, lensbstr);
    }
```

Comment: in the line `str = strstr(str, substr);` you'll get the first occurence of the substring (if it exists). And there you can build a loop as long as you get a str which is not null...

Comment: `strncpy(str, substr, lensbstr);` will NOT nul-terminate the resulting string.

Comment: @wildplasser can you explain? what do you mean by wont null-terminate? :<

Comment: I was wrong. Your usage of stncpy() is equivalent to memcpy() with the same arguments. BTW: do you  realize that strstr() will return NULL if the substring is not found?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a programming exercise, so I’m not going to just give you the answer.  However, I’ll give you a few hints.

Two big problems:

- You don’t have a loop that would replace the second and later instances.
- You are upper-casing the substring... not a copy of the substring. A second pass through replaceSubstring would only match the upper-case version of the substring.

A couple of small problems / style comments:

- str is an array, so its value is always non-zero, so “if(!str)” is never true.
- strncpy is almost never the right answer. It will work here, but you shouldn’t get in the habit of using it. Its behavior is subtle and is rarely what you want. Here it would be faster and more obvious to use memcpy.
- You are upper-casing the substring and measuring its length even if you didn’t find it and so won’t need those results.
- Although using int for flags works and is the traditional way, newer versions of the language have stdbool.h, the “bool” type, and the “true” and “false” constants. Using those is almost always better.
- You appear to intend to stop when the user enters an empty string for the first string. So why do you ask for the second string in that case? It seems like you want an infinite loop and a “break” in the middle.

Comment: thanks for the tips! you're right it is an exercise :)
sorry for not giving any context-- i can only have the libraries that are included.
if user inputs for one string and not the other the program should exit,
(i initially used while (*str_ptr && *substr_ptr) but it wasn't correct for the exercise)


in the function i have tried to make a while loop to check the next occurrence
while (*str){
  the rest of the function
 while incrementing str by substr's length.
}
and i'm going over and i don't really know what to do.
again, thanks!